# Wordpress set custom title on custom page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create entirely custom page but using the same functions for creating header and footers in WP.
I have this on my page

```
<?php
include("../wp-blog-header.php");
get_header();
?>
<title>My Custom Title Here</title>
<?php
wp_head();
get_footer();
?>
```

The page is displaying all fine, but when I am trying to add `<title>My Custom Title Here</title>` after `get_header()` I am getting this in my page source as title `Page not found &#8211; My Custom Title`

How can I set custom page title? I mean after the page loads the title should be `<title>My Custom Title Here</title>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not ideal, but I've done the following in a pinch. With some additional logic you could add it to your functions.php, but if you really just need it for a single page I'd just include the filter in that specific file, before calling `get_header()`.

```
<?php
include("../wp-blog-header.php");

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_title', 1000 );
function custom_title($title) {
    $title = 'My Custom Title Here';
    return $title;
}
get_header();
?>
<?php wp_head(); get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @Illusion  This will work supposing the theme's `add_filter`s aren't overriding it. Try adding a higher priority (3rd parameter), something crazy like 99999. Or search your theme for `add_filter` targeting `wp_title` to see what priority the filter for 404's titles are given.